# Equals implementation with override Equals, IEquatable, == and !=

Tags: c#, equality

I am seeing many posts and questions about equality in C# and how to implement it. I wanted to try to collect the best practices and provide an solution with more or less no boilerplate code where no code is repeated.

Starting of with a simple class like that:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I want now to add to this class every possibility for an `Equals` call starting with overriding it with ReSharper recommendations:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
    if (obj.GetType() != GetType()) return false;

    if(obj is Foo foo)
    {
        // here all the values should be checked
        return Bar == foo.Bar;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now I have overriden the Equals call but are left with the `==` and `!=` operators with that recommendation https://www.loganfranken.com/blog/698/overriding-equals-in-c-part-3/

```
public static bool operator ==(Foo a, 
                               Foo b)
{
    if(ReferenceEquals(null, a)) return false; 
            
    return a.Equals(b); 
}

public static bool operator !=(Foo a,
                               Foo b)
{
    return !(a == b);
}
```

The last step now would be to implement the `IEquatable<>` interface like this and adjusting the override `Equals` leaving the class like this:

```
public class Foo : IEquatable<Foo>
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Foo other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;

        // here all the values should be checked
        return Bar == other.Bar;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (obj.GetType() != GetType()) return false;

        return Equals(obj as Foo);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Foo a,
                                   Foo b)
    {
        if(ReferenceEquals(null, a)) return false;
        
        return a.Equals(b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Foo a,
                                   Foo b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }
}
```

Now in my eyes I have removed more or less all duplicate code (unfortunately I cannot think of a way to get rid of the null-checks). I would implement the "core-logic" in the `Equals(Foo other)` method and the others could be copied to any other classes.

is there any pitfall or problem I am missing here? Or any recommendation on getting lesser code? I am not trying to get the best performance, clean code should be the main criteria in this implementation and reusability for other classes. So would it be possible to copy the last 3 methods without problems to any other class and only implementing the `IEquatable<>` there and changing the call of course?

Also note that I did not implement `GetHashCode()` right now.

Comment: While I applaud your effort to figure out the right way of doing this, there is unfortunately not a single answer and thus your question here will be prone to getting answered primarily based on opinions. Like my opinion, in the first Equals method, instead of doing the check there, also implement `IEquatable<T>` on your type, and call `.Equals(foo)` with a strong type instead.

Comment: *"I wanted to try to collect the best practices and provide an solution with more or less no boilerplate code where no code is repeated."* - remind me of [this](https://xkcd.com/927/).

Comment: `==` and `!=` is used by C# when you write `==` and `!=` and have strongly typed variables. In 99% of all other cases, `.Equals(...)` and `.GetHashCode()` will be used to determine equality.

Comment: If you override `Equals()` you'll also have to overwrite `GetHashCode()`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen ok so for my use cases I think it never makes sense to override `==` as I see right now!

Comment: @Oliver I know but that is not part of the question

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Right you are, my bad. That's what I get for reading docs as soon as I wake up...

Comment: `==` and `!=` should probably only be implemented for types that exhibit value-semantics, in that the fact that they're reference-types is besides the point, but this is my opinion.

Comment: For a *simple* class I'd argue the best practice is to define it as `record Foo(int Bar)` (or, if you must have it mutable, `record Foo { public int Bar { get; set; } }`. Done!

Comment: @JeroenMostert you should mention though that is C# 9 supported on .net 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not *repeat yourself*: implementing `public bool Equals(Foo other)` is enough;
all the other: `Equals`, `==`, `!=` can be derived from `Equals(Foo other)`:

```
public class Foo : IEquatable<Foo>
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Foo other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
 
        if (other is null) return false;

        // here all the values should be checked
        return Bar == other.Bar;
    }

    // Here we can put it short 
    public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is Foo other && Equals(other);

    //TODO: Don't forget about hash 
    // Here I put the easiest approach which exploits the fact we
    // have just one property of type int. 
    public override int GetHashCode() => Bar;

    // Note ReferenceEquals(a, b): we want null == null be true
    public static bool operator == (Foo a, Foo b) =>
      ReferenceEquals(a, b) || (a is not null && a.Equals(b));

    public static bool operator !=(Foo a, Foo b) => !(a == b);
}
```

Comment: That is something I looked for! I know there is no standard but it should be teached like that...

Comment: Requires C# ... 9? ... 'is not' doesn't exist with most C# compilers.

Comment: @Adam: we can use `!=null` instead of `is not null`; however `is not null` is a little (or even tiny) bit accurate in the context: `is not null`: `!=` can be overriden and does not compare with `null`

Comment: Yeah, I assumed for this to work it would need to be !( a is null) ... since using != inside == while using == inside != is a potential recipe for disaster.